# How to plot the fitted vs actual data while model calibrates over training period in Tensorflow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a dataframe containing numerical daily data and a target variable ("Score") in the last column that I am trying to predict. The code below seems to work but I would like to visualise the results of the model fit while the model is calibrating against the actual data in the training set.

All variables are time series so they are ordered in time but the plotting I managed to test shows the actual time series of the target variable (in the training period) but for the predicted values I didn't manage to get the expected results.

If I plot them, the fitted values don't respect the time ordering of the actual data and this seems to be due to the fact that there is a shuffling happening at a earlier stage.

How can I recover the time ordering of the fitted data at each iteration so that I can compare against the actual target variable while the model calibrates?

```
#allData is a dataframe containing the target variable in last column
y = 'Score' #name of the target variable to predict
target = allData[y].shift(1).dropna() #shift by 1 days as I want to predict the future score
X_ = allData.drop([y], axis=1) #all features
df = pd.concat([X_, target], join='outer', axis=1).dropna() #put them all back in a dataframe

df_train = df['2015':'2018']
df_test = df[prediction[0] : prediction[1]]

#scale variables
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train= scaler.fit_transform(df_train.values)
test = scaler.transform(df_test.values)

x_train = train[:, :-1]
y_train = train[:, -1]
x_test = test[:, :-1]

num_features = x_train.shape[1]

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, num_features])
y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])

nl_1, nl_2, nl_3, nl_4 = 512, 256, 128, 64
wi = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(mode='FAN_AVG', uniform=True, factor=1)
zi = tf.zeros_initializer()

# 4 Hidden layers
wt_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(wi([num_features, nl_1]))
bias_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(zi([nl_1]))

wt_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(wi([nl_1, nl_2]))
bias_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(zi([nl_2]))

wt_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(wi([nl_2, nl_3]))
bias_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(zi([nl_3]))

wt_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(wi([nl_3, nl_4]))
bias_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(zi([nl_4]))

# Output layer
wt_out = tf.Variable(wi([nl_4, 1]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(zi([1]))

hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, wt_hidden_1), bias_hidden_1))
hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_1, wt_hidden_2), bias_hidden_2))
hidden_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_2, wt_hidden_3), bias_hidden_3))
hidden_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_3, wt_hidden_4), bias_hidden_4))
out = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_4, wt_out), bias_out))

mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out, y_))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(mse)

session = tf.InteractiveSession()

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

BATCH_SIZE = 100
EPOCHS = 100

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # Shuffle the training data
    shuffle_data = permutation(arange(len(y_train)))
    x_train = x_train[shuffle_data]
    y_train = y_train[shuffle_data]

    # Mini-batch training
    for i in range(len(y_train)//BATCH_SIZE):
        start = i*BATCH_SIZE
        batch_x = x_train[start:start+BATCH_SIZE]
        batch_y = y_train[start:start+BATCH_SIZE]
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})

        # Show plot of fitted model against actual data
        if np.mod(i, 5) == 0:
            pred = session.run(out, feed_dict={x: x_train}) #x_train is scaled
            dd = train.copy()
            dd[:, -1] = pred[0]
            pred = scaler.inverse_transform(dd) #need to rescale in order to compare with actual data
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
            line1, = ax1.plot(df_train[y].values) #the actual data in the training period
            line2, = ax1.plot(pred[:, -1][::-1]) #the fitted data in the training period don't seem to be ordered in time, like the original data
            plt.title('Epoch ' + str(epoch) + ', Batch ' + str(i))
            plt.show()
            plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "*calibrate*", as it is far from a standard term in this setting; if you merely mean "*fit*" (as I suspect you do), please edit & update your post & title accordingly

Comment: Thanks, yes I mean the fitted data. I would like to visualise the fitted time series against the actual data of the target variable.